# How to retrieve Stripe subscription and credit card with one request only?

Tags: stripe-payments

in Stripe version 2020-03-02 I was able to retrieve a `subscription` and its associated `credit_card` in one go like this:

```
stripe_subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve({:id => stripe_subscription_id, :expand => [:customer]})
stripe_customer = stripe_subscription.customer
stripe_credit_card = stripe_customer.sources.data.first
```

In version 2020-08-27 this seems no longer possible since Stripe won't recognise the `sources` attribute on `customer`.

So how can I retrieve a subscription and its credit card with **one** request only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sources` on `Customer` is not included by default, you have to explicitly include it when you expand the related properties. Your code would look like this:

```
stripe_subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve({
  id: stripe_subscription_id,
  expand: ['customer.sources'],
})
stripe_customer = stripe_subscription.customer
stripe_credit_card = stripe_customer.sources.data.first
```

The expand feature is quite powerful and lets you expand multiple separate properties or chain expansion like we did above. I recommend reading the detailed [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) that Stripe shipped.